# unable to perform function on click for i class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Pretty straight-forward question, I know, but don't seem to have an answer.  I have a menu system with classes and a button that states the following:

```
$('.fa-sitemap').on('click', function () {
  $("#colorscreen").remove();
});
```

The HTML part of the menu is as follows:

```
<li>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sitemap"></i>Referrals/Contacts</a>
</li>
```

and the div I am removing:

```
<div id="colorscreen" class="animated"> </div>
```

Basically, the button doesn't work.

Comment: Because you close the `i` tag before the text, so it has no content and is invisible? You ought to put the classes on the `a` tag and style it with CSS.

Comment: @lonesomeday - it probably has content, as it's Font Awesome, the question is if the handler should only work when clicking the icon, or on the text as well ?

Comment: ah right , that is a bit of a problem as it's structure is integrated into the jquery menu http://multi-level-push-menu.make.rs/   .... any way of doing this without going down that road ?

Comment: .... although having said that the a tag might allow it still work , i will try

Comment: Handlers on FontAwesome icons definitely work, in general.

Comment: well i put it in the a tag which makes the script work but the formatting is now all over the place ...   <a href="#" i class="fa fa-sitemap"></i>Referrals/Contacts</a>

Comment: so to get it to work i have to basically re-style my css for the entire menu

Comment: and the icon handler from fotn awesome now isn't recognised eek

Comment: Just to clarify, I have no experience of this library, so ignore my comment if it doesn't seem relevant.

Comment: ok the answer is to create a new class within the a tag and refer to that .... keeps the styling and allows the function to occur !

Comment: @lonesomeday you were basically right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the button to trigger the handler when clicked, selecting the fa-sitemap, you can use this code:

```
$('.fa-sitemap').parent().on('click', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
  $("#colorscreen").remove();
});
```